# Shader breaks camera

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, shader, vbo

I made a shader for my VBO cube (Coloring) and have some problems.

When enabling the shader, I can't move the camera.

My camera breaks with the shader enabled.

Cube.vert:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

// Notice that the "1" here equals the "1" in glVertexAttribPointer
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

Cube.frag:

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 fragmentColor;

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

void main(){
    // Output color = color specified in the vertex shader,
    // interpolated between all 3 surrounding vertices
    color = fragmentColor;
}
```

Comment: what camera are you talking about?

Comment: You probably "move" the camera but because you don't do any world / projection computation in the shader it doesn't have any effect. If `vertexPosition_modelspace` doesn't contain a pre-projected matrix, you simply draw the cube to the screen using it's model data. `gl_Position` should be `projection * view * model`, not just `model`.

Comment: I'm very new to shaders, How can I do that?

Comment: Read [http://open.gl/transformations](http://open.gl/transformations). Don't be put off by all the math behind it, if you need you can skip that part and get it to work without fully knowing what actually goes on behind the scenes. But know that the "camera" basically is the view/projection uniforms you multiply your model data with.

Comment: Ikn what a camera is, but idk how to apply that to the shaders :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: Projection * View * Model

They are all 3 Mat4
Model would be: 1

Then push the stuff back to the shader.